# Class cannot be added on input by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot add a class to this input:
[image]

Here is the jQuery:

```
$( ".payment_nr" ).addClass( "highred" );
```

The HTML:

```
<div>
<input id="email" class="payment_nr" type="email" placeholder="marco@polo.com">
</div>
```

And this is the CSS I want to add:

```
.highred{
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(255,0,0,0.66);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(255,0,0,0.66);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(255,0,0,0.66);
}
```

The weird think is that if I apply it to the parent it works: [image]

```
$( ".payment_nr" ).parent().addClass( "highred" );
```

Also if I add pure CSS directly it works: [image]

```
$( ".payment_nr" ).css("background-color","yellow");
```

Can somebody please help me to add it directly on the input using an external CSS?

Comment: works here http://jsfiddle.net/XpNPR/

Comment: CSS specificity, you probably have styles on a more specific selector set, either that or the styles don't do what you think they do

Comment: The current input only has another class that only adds the width :/

Comment: You can use your browser's inspector tool to see what styles are being applied.

Comment: You present this as a jQuery problem, but I don't think it is. If you (temporarily) change your markup to include `class="payment_nr highred"` does _that_ work?

Comment: Hey guys I just noticed that the site is using Bootstrap and the premade styles doesnt allow to add any other class.

Comment: Does anybody knows how to replace it?

Comment: Just be more specific than the Bootstrap styles.

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't work yet :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't intend for this to be an answer, but rather some things for you to try.

Did you see Krishna's jsFiddle in the comments? Is there anything wrong with his example?

You can add the class either to all elements with class `payment_nr`:

```
$( ".payment_nr" ).addClass( "highred" );
```

Or you can add it to only the inputs with class `payment_nr`:

```
$( "input.payment_nr" ).addClass( "highred" );
```

Or you can add it to the ID for that specific input element:

```
$( "#email" ).addClass( "highred" );
```

Have you used Chrome's F12 (Developer Tools) to watch the element to see if the class is added or not?

Again: please comment on [the jsFiddle that Krishna created](http://jsfiddle.net/XpNPR/) in the first comment. Have you see it?